# How to gracefully stop a java main program running inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I am running a script in eclipse ( java main method program ) which creates threads where each thread processes an excel sheet and then saving the processed data into database. It has been crunching data since 2 days, suddenly today logs which i print after processing each record from the excel stopped.

After some examination found that mongodb has become unresponsive due to which i assume that all the threads are waiting for response. I have restarted my database thinking the program will throw an error but no error was thrown.

The way that my code is written is that after processing a complete sheet it writes a status message into the excel sheet records. This part of the code is written inside a finally block. I have been waiting for the program to terminate by itself but it is still running. I have checked it to be running because  i take input from user for a new excel sheet to read. It is taking input from the user and printing logs. Therefore i  assume the program hasn't become unresponsive.

Is there a way to safely shutdown my program so that all the status logs get printed into the excel sheet. I mean making sure that the code inside the finally block gets executed. There are no shutdown hooks written in the script. The status logs are very important as i have been running this program since the past 2 days.

According to this [link](http://scofaq.aplawrence.com/FAQ_scotec6killminus9.html) killing a program using kill -15 would be safer as it might give the program to do some clean up operations but i'm not sure.

```
public static void validate(String sheetNameWithLocation, String threadName) {
        String fileName = sheetNameWithLocation.substring(sheetNameWithLocation.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        Workbook workbook = null;
        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sheetNameWithLocation);) {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet dataSheet = workbook.getSheet(AppConstants.DATA_SHEET);
            if (dataSheet != null) {
                String countryName = fileName.split("_")[0];
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (int i = 1, count = 1; i <= dataSheet.getLastRowNum() && !shouldICleanUpAndStop; i++, count++) {
                    try {
                        validateAndProcessData(countryName, dataSheet, i, threadName);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        LOGGER.error(threadName + "::Exception occurred for record number:" + i + " Message is :: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    LOGGER.info(threadName + "::status is :: Processed " + count + " records in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
                }
                LOGGER.info(threadName + "::Total time taken to process sheet is::" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
            } else {
                LOGGER.error(threadName + "::DATA sheet is not present. Program exiting....");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to locate file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to load or write to file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (workbook != null) {
                try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(sheetNameWithLocation);) {
                    workbook.write(outputStream);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Unable to locate file");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Unable to load or write to file.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There are no sleep or wait methods being called inside "validateAndProcessData" method. 
**The validate method is called from the run() method overridden from the thread class.**

added a part of the jstack output::

"Attach Listener" #13759 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fddd0001000 nid=0x11ba waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"ThreadID:13" #12918 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fde1c89f000 nid=0x155 runnable [0x00007fdde8bec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x0000000760ccd5b8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
    - locked <0x0000000760cc9168> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    - locked <0x0000000760cc9168> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:303)
    at transaction.script.excelSheet.validators.ExcelSheetsValidator.getlocation(ExcelSheetsValidator.java:428)
    at transaction.script.excelSheet.validators.ExcelSheetsValidator.validateAndProcessData(ExcelSheetsValidator.java:231)
    at transaction.script.excelSheet.validators.ExcelSheetsValidator.validate(ExcelSheetsValidator.java:137)
    at transaction.script.excelSheet.validators.ExcelSheetsValidator.run(ExcelSheetsValidator.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i have added part of my code

Comment: Use `jstack` to get stack trace. That way you can find out where exactly program is stuck.

Comment: @talex i have added the jstack can you help me understanding it

Comment: What is in `ExcelSheetsValidator.getlocation(ExcelSheetsValidator.java:428)`

Comment: @talex that is a call to database which as i mentioned became unresponsive

Comment: According your stack trace it is not. It call `jersy` library which lead to some http request.

Comment: @talex yes i make a make call to the database using a http request using jersey

Comment: I forgot you using `mongo` as database. Then you have not much option. If you really want you can find out socket handler and ask your OS to close it. I'm not experienced enough to give your advice on how to do that. To prevent such situation in future you should configure timeout on your connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can input a char in the console when you want to shutdown

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("close");
        }
    });
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    System.in.read();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But my question was for a program which is already running inside of eclipse. it is not possible to add new code and handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You might have tried this already, but I guess if you have some kind of exception handling for database connection timeout, it might solve your problem.

I am basing this on the line where you have given ***After some examination found that mongodb has become unresponsive due to which i assume that all the threads are waiting for response.***